# VBA excel json string to double conversion not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting a json response, but cannot convert it into a double. The function ignores the decimal places (comma).

Here are my functions:

```
Public Function DownloadDataFromURL(url As String) As String
    Set Myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Myrequest.Open "GET", url
    Myrequest.send
    Dim WebResponse As String
    WebResponse = Myrequest.responseText
    DownloadDataFromURL = WebResponse
End Function

Function getlatestPrice()
   Dim apiKey As String
   Dim latestPriceUrl As String
   Dim result As Double

    apiKey = "xyz"
    latestPriceUrl = "https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/aapl/quote/latestPrice?token="

    Dim url As String
    Dim data As String

    url = latestPriceUrl + apiKey
    data = DownloadDataFromURL(url)
    Debug.Print data

    result = CDbl(data)

    Debug.Print result

End Function
```

The debug output gives me:

351.69

35169

Why is the decimal point missing?

Comment: *“Why is the decimal point missing?”*  Your windows regional settings are using `comma` for the decimal separator; whereas the downloaded JSON is using `dot` for the decimal separator. Possibly your windows regional settings are using `dot` for the thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a local thing. Not sure how to come up with an internationally agnostic save solution for users with different locales.

The solution that worked for countries using a comma instead of a dot:

```
result = CDbl(Replace(data, ".", ","))
```

this works